# Uitextview expand to right

Tags: objective-c

I have a uitextview in a tableviewcell, and I would like to know, how can I get the textview to expand to the right (ie let me keep typing without making line breaks and doing the scrolling thing). thanks

Comment: Im not understanding, can you provide some image based explanation? or some more information?

Answer (score 0):

For every container, just like this one, you can set the maximumNumberOfLines to 1, which will limit the number of line breaks.

Comment: And how is that done? There is no maximumNumberOfLines property on a uitextview...

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simple by set max number of lines

```
textview.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines=1;
```

Comment: @louiskablooie please provide image so i can understand more.